# Lista con comas en PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

En una pagina de `PHP` tengo una consulta de `MySQL` simple. El resultado final es una lista.

La parte que genera el resultado

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<a href='".$row['url']."'>".$row['Name']."</a>, ";
}
```

Esto genera algo como esto:

`Abc123, Def456, Ghi789,`

Pero no quiero ese ultimo coma:

`Abc123, Def456, Ghi789`

¿Como puedo alterar el `PHP` para lograr esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución sería guardar los resultados en una cadena y antes de escribirla por pantalla usando `echo`, eliminar la última coma usando [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) o [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) (porque les puedes pasar una máscara especificando la cadena ", "):

```
$resultado = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $resultado .= "<a href='".$row['url']."'>".$row['Name']."</a>, ";
}
echo rtrim($resultado, ", ");
```

Otra posible solución sería guardar el texto (sin la coma) en un array y luego hacer un [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) uniendo con la coma:

```
$cadenas = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($cadenas, "<a href='".$row['url']."'>".$row['Name']."</a>");
}
echo implode(", ", $cadenas);
```

Comment: ¿Quizás el "downvoter" quiere decir porque?

Comment: Podría ser mas constructivo si aclara el porque del "downvote"? y no votar por votar.

Comment: El array push es lo que necesitaba - Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `substr()` de PHP :

```
$myString = substr($myString, 0, -1);
```

Te quitara el ultimo carácter de la cadena.